# Login Page MongoDB Issue

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I am writing the below Java Script file to create a login/register webpage and keep receiving the error "if (VALID_OPTIONS.indexOf(key) === -1) throw new Error(`\`${key}` is an invalid option.`);Error:` useNewUrlParser` is an invalid option." I have provided the error code as well below. This occurs when trying to run nodeman app.js to yield the "Server Has Started" response. I have installed and the dependencies required to run this so I'm not sure what the issue is, any help is appreciated.

```
var express = require("express"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    passport = require("passport"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose =
        require("passport-local-mongoose"),
    User = require("./models/user");

mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/auth_demo_app");

var app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Rusty is a dog",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//=====================
// ROUTES
//=====================

// Showing home page
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});

// Showing secret page
app.get("/secret", isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render("secret");
});

// Showing register form
app.get("/register", function (req, res) {
    res.render("register");
});

// Handling user signup
app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username
    var password = req.body.password
    User.register(new User({ username: username }),
            password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("register");
        }

        passport.authenticate("local")(
            req, res, function () {
            res.render("secret");
        });
    });
});

//Showing login form
app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});

//Handling user login
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/secret",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function (req, res) {
});

//Handling user logout
app.get("/logout", function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) return next();
    res.redirect("/login");
}

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Server Has Started!");
});
enter code here
```

Error:

```
$ nodemon app.js
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:174
  if (VALID_OPTIONS.indexOf(key) === -1) throw new Error(`\`${key}\` is an invalid option.`);
                                         ^

Error: `useNewUrlParser` is an invalid option.
    at Mongoose.set (node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:174:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Documents\GitHub\CCPS530Project\app.js:10:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
Error: `useNewUrlParser` is an invalid option.
```

Answer (score 0):

Those options have been removed in Mongoose 6. See the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options) for more info.

You can just remove all the 4 of the `.set` lines from your code and it will work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to declare the port on connection when `useNewUrlParser` is set to true:
`mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/auth_demo_app");` (or whatever port you're using)